# Using nodemon and --inspect with serverless

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, google-chrome-devtools, nodemon

I am writing a lambda service and hate having to stop and start the server after every change.

I do have this running together with `chrome --inspect` working correctly:

```
    "start": "node --inspect-brk $(which serverless) invoke local -f getGoldenDeomondotcom"
```

I then used:

```
    "start": "nodemon --exec \"node --inspect-brk $(which serverless) invoke local -f getGoldenDeomondotcom\""
```

to allow me to use nodemon with --inspect, however the messages don't pipe through to chrome.

Any ideas how I could use them together?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use js or replace js in the code below with your language ext e.g py,ts
in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start:dev": "nodemon -e js  --exec \"sls offline\""
},
```

Answer (score 0):

From github ... (https://github.com/akupila)
nodemon --exec "serverless serve start"

I'm using this in package.json during dev:

"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --exec \"serverless serve start\""
}

This allows me to just run npm start. Whenever any file in the project changes nodemon will restart serve.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Anyway seems like serverless supposed to be doing that. https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/931

Answer (score 0):

I'm using serverless-offline and serverless-dynamodb-local, I just added

`"start": "nodemon --exec \"sls offline start\""` to scripts